# How to set Messagebox Color in C# .net 3.0?

Tags: c#

How to set Messagebox  Color in C# .net 3.0  ?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "winforms", there isn't any property for that. You would have to create your own modal message dialog. You *might* be able to use P/Invoke, but I wouldn't bother, tbh.

Answer (score 1):

The `MessageBox` is just meant to be for very simple messages. If you need to customize it more than what it's designed to do I'd suggest that it would be better to write your own dialog to do it. It wouldn't take long to replicate the functionality you need from the `MessageBox` and it would be a lot easier to customize.

Answer (score 1):

for that you need to create your own custom message box.